# update function letter in 7zip

Tags: updates, 7zip

I was trying to learn some of the function letters in 7zip. But i got stuck at 'u' (update) function letter which tells about updation in an archived file. It only updates about the content of file but if i delete some of my sub-directories and files it does not update the archived file. Can anyone tell why is this happening or do anyone have any offcial documentation of update function letter in 7zip. please let me know.

UPDATE:

I am attaching here a screenshot which shows my directory structure.

[image: Directory Structure]

Now, in this whenever i modify some content in a file and run the 'update' command then it updates the archived file accordingly. But if i delete some of the files and subdirectories (let say, i deleted file1 and dir5) , then it does not update the archived file.

FYI, I always run the following command in the dir1 directory.

$ 7z u dir1.7z

Comment: Could you update to list the exact command you are attempting to run and reproduce the contents of the file, if possible with a screenshot or two? This would make it easier to visualise the problem.

Comment: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/update.htm

Comment: @JustInTimeBerlake no screenshots of text, please. Properly formatted text is better.

Comment: @muru my feeling is that it may be useful to have a visual representation of the directory tree structure of the zip file, which while technically possible to reproduce via text may be easier to show via screenshot

Comment: @JustInTimeBerlake and [that much harder to read, copy, or otherwise manipulate and, also unsearchable](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/158442).

Comment: As I said, text please, instead of (or, at least, in addition to) screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

By default archive keep files during an update even if they are removed from source.

If you want to remove files from archive which they are not existing anymore in source path, use this switch: `-uq0`
Be careful with this switch - in case of mistake with bad path to source, data within archive could be lost/wiped.

```
$ 7z u dir1.7z -uq0 "/home/user/source_dir/*"
```

If you want to go through dirs recursively add `-r` switch

```
$ 7z u dir1.7z -uq0 -r "/home/user/source_dir/*"
```

By default 7z is using Solid method to store data - if just one file is different/updated in block where the file belongs, entire block with files within is recompressed then.